# How to compare 2 java.sql.Date in scala?

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark

I have some date in format java.sql.Date and I want to compare them

```
import java.sql.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DateType, IntegerType}
var a = Date.valueOf("2018-11-09")
var b = Date.valueOf("2019-11-09")

a: java.sql.Date = 2018-11-09
b: java.sql.Date = 2019-11-09
```

If I compare with an equal sign it work

```
a == b
res1: Boolean = false
```

But if I want to know which one is bigger than the other it return an error:

```
 a >= b
<console>:37: error: value > is not a member of java.sql.Date
```

I would expect it to return false.

How can I compare a and b.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `java.sql.Date#compareTo`:

```
var a = Date.valueOf("2018-11-09")
var b = Date.valueOf("2019-11-09")

if (b.compareTo(a) > 0) {
    println("Date b is later than date a.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the comparison operators such as `a >= b` instead of `compareTo`, you can: just add

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
```

for `Comparable` types. `java.sql.Date` is actually a bit unusual, because it's `Comparable` with `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date`. So for this type you need type ascription:

```
(a: java.util.Date) >= b
```

Comment: OK, edited (I started writing my answer before yours appeared).

Comment: Hi Alexey Romanov, thank you for your answer however it does not work with me..... I do the import "import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._" but when I tried a>= b I still get the same error...

Comment: @Anneso Edited it.